# number of ascii characters > number of non-ascii characters in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I am using the following codes to detect the description contains non-ascii.

Now I want to set the condition to be **number of ascii characters >  number of non-ascii characters** in description, how should I write it in SQL statement?

```
declare @str varchar(1024)
set @str = '|' + char(9) + '|' + char(10) + '|' + char(13)

-- Add all normal ASCII characters (32 -> 127)
declare @i int
set @i = 32
while @i <= 127
    begin
    -- Uses | to escape, could be any character
    set @str = @str + '|' + char(@i)
    set @i = @i + 1
    end

--select description, locale
select description, productlocale, locale
  FROM [DataExtraction].[dbo].[Feedback]
  where 
 and description like '%[^' + @str + ']%' escape '|'
```

Answer (score 0):

Could use a function:

```
create function dbo.fn_CountAscii(@str varchar(8000))
returns int
as
begin
declare @i int = 1
declare @n int = 0
while @i <= len(@str)
begin
    if ascii(substring(@str, @i, 1)) between 32 and 127
    begin
        set @n = @n + 1
    end
    set @i = @i + 1
end
return @n
end
go

declare @str varchar(8000)
set @str = '|' + char(9) + '|' + char(10) + '|' + char(13)

select @str, 
    convert(float, dbo.fn_CountAscii(@str)) / len(@str) as Ratio,
    case when convert(float, dbo.fn_CountAscii(@str)) / len(@str) > 0.5 then 1 else 0 end as MoreAsciiThanNonAscii
```

This might be horribly slow if your data set is large, but suck it and see

Comment: but I am dealing with description field, how should that put in?

Comment: just replace @str with description e.g. select description, case when convert(float, dbo.fn_CountAscii(description)) / len(description) > 0.5 then 1 else 0 end as MoreAsciiThanNonAscii from [DataExtraction].[dbo].[Feedback]

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way to do something like this that I can think of is to use a Tally (aka Numbers) table. If you are not familiar with the concept you can read about it here: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/

You can either create and populate a Tally table in your database (I create one in my utility database from the get-go because it is so useful) or you can build one on the fly using a CTE but that makes for more code you have to generate. For this post I will use the CTE method so you can just copy and paste the solution to try it out:

```
DECLARE @pString VARCHAR(8000);

SELECT @pString = 'Çüé the quick brown fox which gave me 50¢.';

--===== "Inline" CTE Driven "Tally Table" produces values from 0 up to 10,000... enough to cover VARCHAR(8000)
 WITH E1(N) AS (
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
                ),                          --10E+1 or 10 rows
       E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
       E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
 TallyCTE(N) AS ( --=== This provides the "zero base" and limits the number of rows right up front
                     -- for both a performance gain and prevention of accidental "overruns"
                 SELECT 0 UNION ALL
                 SELECT TOP (DATALENGTH(ISNULL(@pString,1))) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
                )
--===== Return all t.N+1 positions and calculate the length of the element for each starting position
SELECT ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY s.N),
       StartPosition = s.N,
       TheCharacter = SUBSTRING(@pString, N, 1)
FROM TallyCTE s
WHERE N <= LEN(@pString)
    AND ASCII(SUBSTRING(@pString, N, 1)) > 127
```

If you were to persist the Tally table your query could be simplifed like this:

```
    DECLARE @Parameter VARCHAR(8000);
SET @Parameter = 'Çüé,Element01,Element02,Element03,Element04,Element05,50¢';

SELECT  N,
        SUBSTRING(@Parameter, N, 1)
FROM    dbo.Tally
WHERE   N <= LEN(@Parameter)
        AND ASCII(SUBSTRING(@Parameter, N, 1)) > 127
ORDER BY N;
```

Results from both are:

[image]